# Compile ASPX/ASCX into DLL? (i.e. compile on client instead of server?)

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, c#-4.0

If I understand correctly with our deployments most code gets compiled on the workstation, and the aspx/ascx files get compiled on first access on the server. Is there anyway to precompile these?

I would like to do this to trigger compile errors at workstation compile time, rather than at "run-time" and also to potentially allow C# 4 features to work in views as we use .NET 3.5 on the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio provides the command-line tools aspnet_compiler and aspnet_merge, and I [blogged](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/publishing-web-application-projects-from-the-command-line-vs2008/) about how to call them from a batch file.

You can also [add aspnet_compiler as a Post-Build event](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/type-safe-databindings-in-asp-net/) in the project to find compilation errors, but it slows down build times.

If you develop for .Net 4, you need to have the .Net 4 framework installed on the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link for precompilation overview: [ASP.NET Precompilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx)

Also, if on server 4th framework doesn't installed you can't use C#4 features in your project even if you will precompile application on your dev machine.